# Chrome specific flash repaint youtube video api

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, youtube-javascript-api

I am using the youtube api to create a flash video inside of a twitter bootstrap modal. It works fine in all browsers except in chrome. After closing the modal and hovering over buttons or images fragments of the video appear in there place. I tried changing wmodes, opacity, visibility. I can't post a link because it's a client project that is in development. Does anyone have any experience with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you recreate the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/ ???

Comment: Try to do a jsfiddle and I couldn't get it be happen there, but in doing so this led me to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The default css3 transition properties that are for the bootstrap modals were causing a repaint issue. After removing the transitions this no longer occurred.